# kotlin + aws lambda requiring empty constructor

Tags: kotlin, guice

I have the following class written in Kotlin+Guice that is invoked with a lambda

```
class LambdaProcessor @Inject constructor(private val s3Util: S3Util) {

    fun lambdaInvokesThisMethod() {
        s3Util.DoSomething()
    }
}
```

That works great for unit testing, but lambda requires the class to have an empty constructor.

I can convert this same class to have an empty constructor by doing this:

```
class LambdaProcessor {

    @Inject lateinit var s3Util: S3Util

    init {
        Guice.createInjector(GuiceDependencyInjector()).injectMembers(this)
    }

    fun lambdaInvokesThisMethod() {
        s3Util.DoSomething()
    }
}
```

That code now works great on lambda but I can't mock s3Util in my unit tests anymore because the init method gets called.

How can I get both scenarios to work together?

Comment: You could use the class you want to inject with guice as delegate in the class you want Lambda to use. I.e. rename the class in example #1 and inject it in example #2. That way you have a class you can test and one that is just a fairly empty container just for lambda that doesn't need testing

Comment: Yeah, that was one idea I had too, it just seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kotlin, if you have a default constructor then all your other constructors **must** call your default.  But, you can have multiple constructors **without** a default constructor.  Here is the final code we used.

```
class LambdaProcessor {

    @Inject private lateinit var s3Util: S3Util

    /**
     * Lambda calls the no-arg constructor, use our IoC library to initialize our dependencies
     */
    constructor() {
        Guice.createInjector(GuiceDependencyInjector()).injectMembers(this)
    }

    /*
     * Unit-testing constructor
     */
    constructor(s3Util: S3Util) {
        this.s3Util = s3Util
    }

    fun lambdaInvokesThisMethod() {
        s3Util.DoSomething()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always declare secondary [constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors). However all of them need to call primary constructor, so there's a trick to make it `private` and handle arguments in init block accordingly.

I don't use `Guice` but you could try something like this:

```
class LambdaProcessor private constructor(s3Util: S3Util?){
    @Inject
    lateinit var s3Util : S3Util

    init{
        s3Util?.let { this.s3Util = it }
    }

    // passes null to primary constructor, leaving field uninitalized
    constructor() : this(null){
        Guice.createInjector(GuiceDependencyInjector()).injectMembers(this)
    }

    // passes non-null to primary constructor initializing the field (cast to nullable needed to match primary signature)
    constructor(s3Util: S3Util) : this(s3Util as S3Util?)

    fun lambdaInvokesThisMethod() {
        s3Util.DoSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this was helpful in getting to my solution below.